# My NSMutableArray doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

sorry for my stupid question (beginner)
I got the demo program Accelerometergraph the apple site and would like to use
NSMutableArray in the values of acceleration x.
but my NSMutableArray contains only one object, there being several passage
NSMutableArray routine and should contain the same number of objects that the counter
show, how code below

```
if(!isPaused)
{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [filter addAcceleration:acceleration];
    [unfiltered addX:acceleration.x y:acceleration.y z:acceleration.z];
    NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:acceleration.x];
    [array addObject:number];

    ++a;
    if (a == 30)  // only check the # objs of mutablearray
    {
        sleep(2);
    }
    [filtered addX:filter.x y:filter.y z:filter.z];
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly if you want help.

Comment: Your NSNumber initialization can be simplified by doing the following, I believe: `NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.x];`

Comment: Also, because you never `release` the `NSNumber` object you create, you're leaking memory.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing a loop of some kind.  The code you list above:

- Makes sure something isn't paused.
- Creates a new (empty) mutable array.
- Adds a value to the new array.
- And does some other work.

My guess is that this whole if{} block sits inside some kind of loop.  You need to alloc and init the mutable array outside of the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new array each time the `if` block is entered, so the `addObject:` will only add the object to the most recently created array.

Furthermore, you are leaking the `array` and `number` objects. Each time you allocate an object, you are responsible for releasing it. Make sure you're familiar with the guidelines set out in the [memory management programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).